# Generated test fails when unit testing component inside the library

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nrwl

My project was created using nx schematics, and I'm having some components inside libraries that I want to unit test using jest.js. Every test fails with following errors:

```
● MyComponent › should create

    Failed: "Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone.js"

       7 |   let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
       8 | 
    >  9 |   beforeEach(async(() => {
         |   ^
      10 |     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      11 |       declarations: [ MyComponent ]
      12 |     })

      at Env.beforeEach (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:41:24)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (libs/componentlib/src/lib/components/my-component/my-component.component.spec.ts:9:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (libs/componentlib/src/lib/components/my-component/my-component.component.spec.ts:5:1)

  ● MyComponent › should create

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null

      at TestBedViewEngine._initIfNeeded (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:393:46)
      at TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:594:10)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:247:36)
      at Object.<anonymous> (libs/componentlib/src/lib/components/my-component/my-component.component.spec.ts:17:23)

  ● MyComponent › should create

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: undefined

      21 | 
      22 |   it('should create', () => {
    > 23 |     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
         |                       ^
      24 |   });
      25 | });
      26 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (libs/componentlib/src/lib/components/my-component/my-component.component.spec.ts:23:23)
```

I've tried already to import zone.js in spec files, importing modules, removing async, reseting the test environment before each test, but everything fails with some different error. I should mention also that I'm using clarity components from vmware.

Here's the .spec file:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I was expecting that this should work like intended when using nx. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution!

The problem was that jest was not configured out of box, when creating nx workspace. So I took this steps to make it work:

**1. Install [jest-zone-patch](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-zone-patch)**

```
npm install jest-zone-patch --save-dev
```

**2. Edit files**

For each library you have to edit test-setup.ts file to look like this:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';

import 'jest-zone-patch';
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import './jestGlobalMocks';
```

Also, add `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts']` to `jest.config.js` file of your library, so it looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'my-library',
  preset: '../../../jest.config.js',
  coverageDirectory: '../../../coverage/libs/administration/identification',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts']
};
```

and add `jestGlobalMocks.ts` file in the same folder as `test-setup.ts` file. You can find it [here](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/blob/master/example/src/jestGlobalMocks.ts), or just copy the code bellow:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'CSS', {value: null});
Object.defineProperty(document, 'doctype', {
  value: '<!DOCTYPE html>'
});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      display: 'none',
      appearance: ['-webkit-appearance']
    };
  }
});
/**
 * ISSUE: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7101
 * Workaround for JSDOM missing transform property
 */
Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
```

**3. Change spec files**

Change your generated spec file to something like this:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This way, component and fixture are created, after `compileComponents` promise has finished, thus avoiding race conditions and potential *undefined* error in `'should create'` unit test.

**4. Run library test**

Finnaly, you can run your test and hopefully it will pass.

```
ng test my-library
```

Hope that this will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

## I just encountered the same problem.

Using [Nrwl's Nx](https://nx.dev/angular) to scaffold a new application plus a "feature-shell" library (the design pattern suggested by Nx's "[Enterprise Angular Monorepo Patterns](https://go.nrwl.io/angular-enterprise-monorepo-patterns-new-book?utm_campaign=Book%3A%20Monorepo%20Patterns%2C%20Jan%202019&utm_source=Github&utm_medium=Banner%20Ad)" book), I was also confused why my Jest unit tests for Angular component classes worked out of the box inside of `apps/`, but not `libs/`.

### I may have found a simpler solution:

Look inside of `angular.json` in the workspace root. Take note of the property `projects.<your-app>.architect.test.options.setupFile`. Its value should be something like `"apps/<your-app>/src/test-setup.ts"`.

The solution that worked for me was adding that exact property and value in `angular.json` to `projects.<your-lib>.architect.test.options`.

### Example Solution

```
// angular.json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "test": {
          ...
          "setupFile": "apps/my-app/src/test-setup.ts" // <- This was already here...
        }
      }
    },
    "my-lib": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "test": {
          ...
          "setupFile": "apps/my-app/src/test-setup.ts" // <- ...and I just added it here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully that one-liner works for you, too!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is using Jest with Angular 11 and experiencing this issue, what fixed it for me was.

Making sure I had these two properties in my `package.json` file.

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
    ],
  }
}
```

**setupJest.ts**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular'
```

Also make sure your jest config doesn't include `"testEnvironment": "node",`. I copied this over from a node project and it broke the tests for me  as well.

Comment: I have the same files as yours, just add Jest for Angular project, the error still exists